# Is it possible to Rename or give a custom name to a Build in VSTS?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

Is it possible to Rename or give a custom name to a Build in VSTS?

What I want to do is have my builds named after the version number. The version number is written in a `.version` file in the root directory.

The intended name would be: `$(MyVersionNumber):$(Rev:rr)`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can update the build number for current build through [Logging Command](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md) (e.g. `Write-Host "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]buildnumber"`).

Simple workflow of your code:

1. Include `$(rev:.r)` in default build number format (Options), for example: `$(date:yyyyMMdd)-$(rev:.r)`
2. Get current build number from [pre-defined variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/build/variables?tabs=batch) (`Build.BuildNumber/BUILD_BUILDNUMBER`)
3. Get the rev value from this build number in your code
4. Read version number from `.version` file
5. Update build number through Logging Command

Answer (score 3):

Under your build definition you can customize the build name (*Build number format*):

For example, I added the date variable `$(Date:dd.MM.yyyy)` with a specific format to the field **`Build number format`**:

[image: Build number format]

[Microsoft Docs, reference article](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/build/options#build-number-format)